# Am the ODBC driver of MS Access .md and .accdb files only can handle 64 executions?

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc, driver

Im writing a C# program where i need to use the Odbc api to connect to a .mdb database file.

After the planning, implementation and tests, now theres a BIG problem.
It seems to be, that the MS Access driver can only handles exact 64 executions.
After that, the program has to restart.
Can someone confirm this issue?

Or were there other drivers, which were also more performant?

Greetings .. :)

Comment: See following.  Not the 32 bit driver in the WOW64 folder : https://superuser.com/questions/1445145/can-i-connect-64-bit-ms-access-to-a-32-bit-odbc-driver

Comment: I do not use the 32 bit driver, i use 64. But there are only 64 connections at the runtime of my application

Comment: Access can handle up to 255 simultaneous connections, or an infinite amount of subsequent connections, so as long as you properly dispose of connections after you're done with them there shouldn't be an issue. Since you appear to be having a problem, please provide a [mre]

Comment: When you say "64 executions" do you mean that you can only execute 64 queries (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, etc.) before needing to restart the application?

Comment: @GordThompson correct..

Comment: Im now at the point to checkout the performance of odbc controlling sql tables, and after a few benchmarks, i founded out this problem

Comment: @ErikA i thought this too, because these odbc ist working with a web api. But i did not use more than 10/20 executions at a time for development. now im trying some benchmarks, and i have to restart the server to continue

Comment: IIRC, one of the reasons why Jet/ACE is not suitable for use as a back-end database for a web server is that it is not designed for multi-threaded applications.

Answer (score 0):

After the idea of checking the cleanups of the resources, i got the answer .. -.- :

The "using" directive from C# to handle resources had no affect on the OdbcConnection object.
You *have* to call the Disponse method right before the next closing bracket.
This closing bracket calls the Disponse method, but - I REALLY DONT KNOW WHY - this had no affect.

```
using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(string.Format(connStr, odbcDriver,
dbq, pwd)))
{
      conn.Open();
      Console.WriteLine($"Conn Create");
      await using OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
      await cmd.CommandText = "select * from [testmodel];";
      cmd.Prepare();
      DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      Console.WriteLine($"DB EXEC COUNT '{i}'");
      await conn.DisposeAsync();
}
```

I tried out pyhons pyodbc to reproduce, that it is not a language issue .. well
it worked fine..

```
with pyodbc.connect(f"Driver={dbAccessDriver};Dbq={dbFilePath};Pwd={dbPassword}") as conn:
            conn: pyodbc.Connection
            cmd: pyodbc.Cursor = conn.cursor()
            cmd.execute("insert into [testmodel] values (?, ?)", (i, "Name " + str(i)))
            cmd.commit()
```

Greetings to all programmers ..

#### Update 19.01.2021

Well, my last answer wasnt as correct as I expect.
I thought i had solved this problem, but its not.

Actually, my last solution has based on the disposed method after the using syntax of the connection and that has to work, because the triggered Disposed event is always the same.
The corrent solution is:
The problem is caused by reading from a table.
If reader were not closed OR disposed, this caused the error.

If you want to control the connections you have to go deeper and control read and write operations.

Comment: But you using two VERY different approaches. First up you using async calls with await in the first example. But why? If the query takes 2 hours, you STILL have the await, and thus will return to that same line if you have that await anyway. As a result, I would re-test with removal of the awaits. But to suggest a non async and async examples are similar in any way, shape or form is a considerable factor here.  The using command should clean up for you - and I never had to use dispose with a using block of code. I would re-test without await. Is this desktop or web?

Comment: However, the await's don't matter. It does stop at 64. This suggests that the connection pooling limit is being reached. A AM VERY surprised that even my test shows 64 is the limit. A conneciton.close does fix this - but I always thought that using blocks would take care of this.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! This test just present the case of open a connection.Thats a very annoying feature, but im happpy, that others can reproduce this problem!

Comment: To say the least - I am near shocked!!! - Now in .net + Access, I always opened a connection and re-used it. The reason is that if you have mutli-user, then a file open can take 20 seconds on a network - due to file security in windows - so things can become slow as a turtle, and I re-use a single given connection as a result. However, EVERYTHING I have read over and over ALWAYS stated that a Using block of code is super good, super safe and it cleans up after! - NOT!!!!! - So this is a real surprise. I suspect this is due to connection pooling, and some setting in ODBC might fix this.